# Copy comma-delimited file from S3 with FREGEXPARSER

Tags: csv, vertica

I would like to understand if I can use `fregexparser()` in the `COPY` command  for a comma delimited file, and if yes, how the pattern of the parser should be written.

Suppose I am trying to load data to a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.Corporate_Accounts
(
    Corporate_Account_GK varchar(1000),
    Corporate_Account_Name varchar(1000),
    Country_Symbol varchar(1000),
    Country_Key varchar(1000)
}
```

and the data is loaded from a text comma-delimited file, how the copy command should look like?

Comment: Is there a reason that you want to use the `fregexparser` parser?  Are you really looking for an example for a different use case or are you really just parsing a csv?  If just a csv, you don't need a special parser for it.

Comment: The other question is, what does the actual input file look like?  The two inputs to constructing a COPY statement are the table info and the file layout.

Comment: Yes , I am actually trying to parse csv file , the reason I am trying regex is that I did not find delimiter that upload all the data .

Comment: Actually the issue is that I need to upload to Vertiac files that were extracted from SQL server with bsp command .

Comment: Well, if it truly is a comma-delimited file, then there shouldn't be a problem with doing a COPY with DELIMITER ','.  You'll have to supply more info, though. Example of the input would help a lot.